# firebase cloud functions onFinalize trigger with not predefined bucket?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Is it possible to write a firebase cloud function that triggers when a new fila was created in firebase storage - onFinalize (but we don't know the exact bucket in advance) ?

Inside my firebase storage a have a folder 'loads' and inside I have folders named with load id like:

- /loads/-Lw1UySdunYyFMrrV6tl
- /loads/-LwisA5hkNl_uxw3k36f
- /loads/-LwkPUm-q7wNv-wZ49Un

https://ibb.co/NnQkTyC here's a screenshot of storage

I want to trigger cloud function when new file has been created inside one of these folders. I don't know in andvance where the file will be created. I don't know if this is even possible. That's why I need an advice.

My main goal is to merge 2 pdf files in one within cloud functions. In my app (TMS written with vuejs) on frontend I create confirmationOrder.pdf using html2canvas/jsPDF and then save it to storage/loads/${loadID}. And later on user can manually upload POD.pdf on the same bucket. When it happens I want my cloud function to merge these two pdfs in one new file (in same storage bucket). But again I don't know the bucket in advance.

Here's how I upload PDFs in frontend:

```
 async uploadConfPDF({ commit }, payload) {
      const PDF = payload.PDF;
      const loadID = payload.loadID;
      const fileName = payload.fileName;

      const fileData = await firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(`loads/${loadID}/${fileName}.pdf`)
        .put(PDF);

      const confOrderURL = await fileData.ref.getDownloadURL();

      return confOrderURL;
    },
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Sorry if my explanation could seem not clear enough. English is not my native language.

Comment: Can you show a picture of your Cloud Storage console. And if you have some existing, code , can you also share it?Are you sure you are using several **buckets**. Aren't you referring to different [References](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference)?

Comment: Please edit the question to show all relevant code so we can see what you're doing, including both client and server code that you have so far.  You should explain exactly what is not working the way you expect with that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT FOLLOWING YOUR QUESTION RE-WORKING**

Based on your code and on the print screen of your Cloud Storage console, you are working in the default bucket of your project, which location's URL is `gs://alex-logistics.appspot.com`.

As we can see on the print screen of your Cloud Storage console, the files in your bucket are presented **in a hierarchical structure**, just like the file system on your local hard disk. However, this is just a way of presenting the files: there aren't genuine folders/directories in a bucket, the Cloud Storage console just uses the different part of the files paths to "simulate" a folder structure.

---

So, based on the above paragraphs, I think that your question can be re-phrased to "*In a Cloud Function, how can I extract the different parts of the path of a file that is uploaded to the default bucket of my Firebase Project?*".

**Answer:**

In a Cloud Function that is triggered when a file is added to the default bucket, you can get the file path as follows:

```
exports.yourCloudFunction = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {

    const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.

    //...

});
```

Since we use an [`onFinalize`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_storage_.objectbuilder.html#on-finalize) event handler, you get the path of this new file by using the [`name`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_storage_.objectmetadata.html#name) property of the `object` Object, which is of type [`ObjectMetadata`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_storage_.objectmetadata.html).

You can then use some [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) methods to, for example, extract from this path the `${loadID}` you refer to in your question.

Comment: I have editted my question to be more clear to understand. I don't know the bucket in advance. That's the problem.

Comment: @nickstojanovic Are you sure that you are using different buckets? From you new edition it seems you are having different paths but in the same bucket. Can you edit your question with a screen shot of your Cloud Storage console + the code you use to upload the PDFs

Comment: In addition, note that **none** of the Firebase client libraries for mobile and web clients can create a new Cloud Storage bucket (including the JS SDK used in Vue.js). That is a privileged operation and is reserved for only the CLI and server SDKs running from a privileged environment.

Comment: I'm bad in terminology. The bucket is just the same. But the path is different.

Comment: I have edited my question with a screenshot and code. Thank you for your answers! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @nickstojanovic thanks for the update. You should look at my answer, since I think IMHO that it answers your question. You should use object.name to get the path and then extract the part of the path that “you don’t know”.

Comment: I have another problem. When I try to console.log something in my function nothing shows up in browser console ((

`exports.testCloudFunc = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async object => {
  const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
  console.log('Done!');
  console.log(object);
  if (object.name === 'POD.pdf') {
    console.log('POD has been uploaded!');
  }
});`

Comment: @Madcap A Cloud Functions is not executed in the brower, it is executed in the back-end in Google Cloud infrastructure. You can view the logs in the Firebase console for Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thank you! Accepted your answer! You really helped me!

Comment: You should install logging module and then import it like that:
`const { Logging } = require('@google-cloud/logging');`
Then console.log should work as usual. The logs will appear in firebase console -> logs page